# How do you order an @HTML.EditorFor call?

Tags: razor

I have a defined enum

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Clinton.Core.Domain.Enums
{
    public enum ReceiptType
    {
        [Display(Name = "Cash")]
        Cash = 0,
        [Display(Name = "Debit Order")]
        DebitOrder = 1,
        [Display(Name = "Credit Card")]
        Cheque = 2,
    }
}
```

Which is then used in a class

```
using Clinton.Core.ReportHelperInterface;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Clinton.Core.Domain.Enums;

namespace Clinton.Persistance.ReportHelper
{
    public class ReturnReceiptType : IReturnReceiptType
    {
        public string GetReceiptType(ReceiptType receiptType)
        {
            return Enum.GetName(typeof(ReceiptType), receiptType);
        }
    }
}
```

This works great but orders it according to the assigned number value where I need to order it alphabetically by name.  I cannot just rework the numbers manually as thete is a lot of legacy information and reports that already utilise the stored enum.  Is there a way to set the

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReceiptType)
```

statement to order by?

Thanks

Comment: What kind of input element that generated by `EditorFor`? I didn't understand if you want ordering from `GetReceiptType` or ordering with `OrderBy` function like `return ((ReceiptType[])Enum.GetName(typeof(ReceiptType))).OrderBy(x => x);` to order the enum values.

Comment: Hi I am haopy to do the orderby on either the enum return function or the HTMLEditFor